# Grunt SASS contrib does not generate css files in target directory

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, prestashop-1.6

I am new to SASS and I am trying to compile `.scss` files of a Prestashop template locally using [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass). It is configured as following:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            compass: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '_theme/themes/swat-theme/sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '../css',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

When I run `grunt sass` on the command line, it diplays:

> Done, without errors

Yet, when I check in the target directory, new `.css` files are not created (I have also tried to delete some before running `grunt sass`).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does running `grunt sass --verbose` say?

Comment: That grunt-contrib-sass has a bug loool. It does not take the cwd into account when computing the dest. My files have been created, but one level above the root of my project directory...

Comment: Reported the issue: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to modify the `dest`:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            compass: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '_theme/themes/swat-theme/sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '_theme/themes/swat-theme/css',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```